# Make UIView.animate appear within a subview instead of superview Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

For the .curveEaseOut UIView.animation, it begins at the superview and you can see it slide onto the screen. Through the current code:

```
    class animationView: UIView {
    
    enum Direction: Int {
        case FromLeft = 0
        case FromRgiht = 1
    }
    @IBInspectable var direction: Int = 0
    @IBInspectable var delay: Double = 0.0
    
    func animateRating() {
        initAnime()
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: self.delay, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
            if let s = self.superview {
                if self.direction == Direction.FromLeft.rawValue {
                    self.center.x += s.bounds.width
                } else {
                    self.center.x -= s.bounds.width
                }
            }
        }, completion: nil)
    }
    
    func initAnime() {
        if let s = self.superview {
            if direction == Direction.FromLeft.rawValue {
                self.center.x -= s.bounds.width
            } else {
                self.center.x += s.bounds.width
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How do you make the animation begin within the subview, instead of the superview. In other words, make it not appear outside of the UIView bounds. The UIView that is animated is already in another UIView. The goal is for the .curveEaseOut to appear within the parent UIView, not the superview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, don't confuse yourself with `superview` and `parent`. A subview's *parent* ***IS*** the subview's *superview*.

However, the reason your `className` subview (terrible class name, by the way) does not "appear within its parent view" is because you don't have Clips To Bounds set on the parent view.

You can either set it when / where you create these views, or add a line in `initAnime()` to make sure it's set:

```
func initAnime() {
    if let s = self.superview {

        // add this line
        s.clipsToBounds = true

        if direction == Direction.FromLeft.rawValue {
            self.center.x -= s.bounds.width
        } else {
            self.center.x += s.bounds.width
        }
    }
}
```